# If a form is missing the submit button, will the form still work to bots?

Tags: forms, security, form-submit, bots

As a security measure, if I replace the `<button type="submit">` with a `<a class="button">` will the form still work for bots?

Comment: Does the `<form>` still have `action`, and `method`, attributes?

Comment: How is that a security measure?

Comment: For demo purposes, I want to disable the form functionality, that simple.

Answer (score 0):

Normally yes, unless you check server side for that button being submitted along with the form.

Answer (score 0):

If the form still has an action attribute attached to it, then it can still be submitted.

Try this for example:

```
document.getElementById("yourform").submit()
```